# FFMPEG complex filter buffer overflow

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg 3.0.2 blend and concat filters together. Here is the command-line:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 \
-loop 1 -t 40 -i img/01.png \
-loop 1 -t 40 -i img/02.png \
-filter_complex "\
[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.9),1,T/0.9))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.9),1,T/0.9)))'[b1v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[vout]" \
-map "[vout]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -c:v libx264 -qp 22 -preset ultrafast -shortest out.mp4
```

It gives me:

```
[Parsed_blend_0 @ 0xb4a8a60] [framesync @ 0xb4a8ae4] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
Last message repeated 21 times
```

Could someone be so kind as to confirm whether there is the same behavior on their machines?

Comment: Hey, Did you perform this in android device?

Comment: @Nisarg How do you tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I get the overflow error here too. Since your blend finishes within a second, you can use the command below to avoid the error

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 40 -i img/01.png \
-loop 1 -t 40 -i img/02.png \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]trim=duration=1[a]; \
[1:v][a]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.9),1,T/0.9))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.9),1,T/0.9)))':shortest=1[b1v]; \
[0:v][b1v][1:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[vout]" \
-map "[vout]" -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -c:v libx264 -qp 22 -preset ultrafast -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you. It really solved the problem I'd been trying to deal with for 2 days.